# Click on Pop up

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

does anyone know how I can get past this pop-up using selenium? When I log into Facebook regularly it doesn't come up but for some reason unknown to me, it keeps firing up when I run my script.

```
cookie_button = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button[id='u_0_j_I5']"))).click()
```

This is the script I'm trying to use to get rid of it but it isn't working

[image]

Comment: Which button you are trying to click ? is it `Allow Selected Cookies`? If yes, can you share relevant HTML code ?

Comment: Yes, <button value="1" class="_42ft _4jy0 _9xo7 _4jy3 _4jy1 selected _51sy" data-cookiebanner="accept_button" data-testid="cookie-policy-dialog-accept-button" title="Allow All Cookies" type="submit" id="u_0_j_+o">Allow All Cookies</button>

Comment: Thank you, Please see below.

Answer (score 0):

The css selector that you are using:

```
button[id='u_0_j_I5']
```

looks dynamic and brittle in nature. What that means is, every time you refresh a page you would see a different id generated from the backend.

I would suggest you use a locator which should be reliable and not too easy to break.

**A CSS:**

```
input[data-cookiebanner='accept_button']
```

or **XPath**

```
//input[@data-cookiebanner='accept_button']
```

but you should be mindful of the uniqueness of the locator.

Please check in the `dev tools` (Google chrome) if we have **unique** entry in `HTML DOM` or not.

**Steps to check:**

`Press F12 in Chrome` -> go to `element` section -> do a `CTRL  + F` -> then paste the `xpath/css` and see, if your desired `element` is getting **highlighted** with `1/1` matching node.

If they are unique, then you can use the below code:

```
cookie_button = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input[data-cookiebanner='accept_button']")))
cookie_button.click()
```

**Update:**

Use the below XPath:

```
//button[contains(text(),'Allow All Cookies')]
```

and click it like this:

```
cookie_button = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[contains(text(),'Allow All Cookies')]")))
cookie_button.click()
```

Comment: I've put in the css/xpath and nothing is being highlighted

Comment: If that's the case check if it's under iframes which you then needs to switch to.

Comment: @David: Please see the above-updated section. Hope that helps.